# how python translate millisecond level string to Date-field(postgresql) and insert it

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a time string, the length of the string is 13.   example '1234567890123' . I want to insert it to postgresql(Django) as Date-field which should keep the precise at millisecond level .

Can you help me, better could have the example code ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use native Python types.  Divide by 1000 to convert your timestamp from millis to seconds.  This assumes you're using POSIX time and *not* UTC, and not some other epoch.

```
import datetime
from __future__ import division
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1234567890123/1000))
```

The output is:

```
2009-02-13 15:31:30.123000
```

Comment: thanks, Dietrich. I t help me a lot.  Do you know how to revert back from 2009-02-13 15:31:30.123000 to  "1234567890123"

Comment: That's an unrelated question (use the "Ask Question" button at the top, or read the Python documentation). "2009-02-13 15:31:30.123000" is just what you get when you print out the datetime object, it's not the actual result of `fromtimestamp()`.